# Route to separate action if request contains a query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I was wondering if I can have the route setup so that the show route with parameter goes to another method and when it doesn't have parameter goes back to the show method.

```
get fruits/:id   fruits#show
```

and

```
get fruits/id?market=XXX     fruits#market
```

I want to do this because I want am reloading that page via ajax and I do a popstatus to add that url in. It would be great to make that work with the route that way

Comment: I don't think thats a good idea. You should have different routes or redirect to a different route if the param exists. This is just an idea not sure why you need this

Comment: Not sure how your app is set up, but consider using nested resources?  If these associate with eachother then it would be good to have market/:id/fruits/:id

Answer (score 6):

Use a route constraint.

```
get 'fruits/:id', to: 'fruits#market', \ 
                   constraints: ->(request) { request.query_parameters.present? }

get 'fruits/:id', to: 'fruits#show'
```

You can also check if a specific parameter is present, for example `market`:

```
get 'fruits/:id', to: 'fruits#market', \ 
          constraints: ->(request) { request.query_parameters[:market].present? }
```